# I'm running on weekends or I run on the weekend?

Tags: present-continuous

Is **I'm running on weekends** right?

I mean this as a habit in the present but I'm not confident I'll keep doing that for a long time.

Comment: Nothing about the Present Continuous verb form implies "I'm not confident I'll keep doing that for a long time". To convey that implication: *I'm **currently** running on weekends* (or *...at the weekend*). Personally, I don't find *I currently run on weekends* particularly idiomatic, but others may feel different about that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The expression "**at** the weekend" must be exclusively a UK thing - it's not used at all in the US. To me, "on weekends" is the most natural sounding way of phrasing it. I guess a more general pattern is that we use "at" with *times* and "on" with *days*. So, "on Tuesday," "on Christmas," but "at 2:00," "at noon."

Comment: @QuackE.Duck: 50 years ago, my enjoyment of *Out on the Weekend* on Neil Young's *Harvest* album was always slightly thrown out of kilter by that "peculiar" new-to-me-at-the-time preposition use. I hear it all the time now, but I've never *quite* got used to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal and neutral expression would be "I run on weekends" (or on the weekend).  If you use "I'm running" you imply that it is particularly temporary, and you expect to stop.

> I'm running on weekends now, because my bike is broken.

The implication here is that you'll stop running as soon as your bike is repaired. The period that you expect to be running on the weekends is particularly short.

So ultimately, both are correct, and you can decide what aspect (habit or temporary) you want to emphasise. But remember the "neutral" language is "I run on the weekend".